# "new FileInputStream()" always get the old stream.

Tags: java, fileinputstream

I'm working on a Java project. In my project I need a FileInputStream and I get it with the followed code:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("test");
```

but the problem is every time I get the old FileInputStream whose name is "test" but not a new one. Is there any method to avoid this behavior? Thank you!

Comment: You get a `FileInputStream` around a `File`. Please clarify what you expect.

Comment: When you pass in the file name `"test"` why do you expect to get a stream for a different file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that the FileInputStream is fully closed before using another FileInputStream within your method.

```
fis.close();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("test");
```